# Writing to a file from python also adds additional characters to the last line

Tags: python, file-handling, file-writing

I have a python file named `constants.py` with the following contents

```
from pytestLoop.config.testdata_005_connect_for_bank_statements import *

xpath_username="//div[text()='"+uname+"']"
pswd="//div[@id='password']"

# this is the end of the file.
```

I have another python file called `alterConstants.py` with the following contents

```
def changeConstants(fname):
    f = open("pytestLoop/config/constants.py",'r+')
    line = f.read()
    text=(line[line.index('config.') + 7:line.index(' import')])
    linenew = line.replace(text, fname)
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(linenew)
    f.close()

changeConstants("testdata_001")
```

after i execute the above `alterConstants.py` file, this is the content of `constants.py`

```
from pytestLoop.config.testdata_001 import *

xpath_username="//div[text()='"+uname+"']"
pswd="//div[@id='password']"

# this is the end of the file.his is the end of the file.
```

my initial goal is to change the line `from pytestLoop.config.testdata_005_connect_for_ban_statementsimport *` to import whatever filename I pass in the `changeConstants` function in `alterConstants.py` **which is working fine**

but python also writes some additional characters to the last line of the `constants.py` file

1. Can someone please explain why does this happen ?
2. Also please suggest on How to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

It's not writing extra characters, it's leaving behind the original characters from the older, larger file. You need to truncate the file to the new length to remove the extra content:

```
def changeConstants(fname):
    with open("pytestLoop/config/constants.py",'r+') as f:
        line = f.read()
        text = line[line.index('config.') + 7:line.index(' import')]
        linenew = line.replace(text, fname)
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(linenew)
        f.truncate()  # Trims file to match the current file offset
```

If the new file data is larger, the `truncate` doesn't do anything, but when the data is shorter, it trims the file down to match the file offset produced by writing the new data.

I also changed your code to use `with` to manage file lifetime (removing the need to explicitly close it, and guaranteeing it gets closed even if an exception occurs during processing).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the explanation. I wasn't aware that python writes the remaining characters produced from the difference. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @FuzeTest Python does not write those remaining characters. If you only ``seek(0)``, you never tell Python to *remove* them in the first place. Everything that is not overwritten by a new ``write`` remains.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi : oh okay, understood, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of seeking back to the start of the file (which leaves the old content intact), open the file again for writing.

```py
def changeConstants(fname):
    with open("pytestLoop/config/constants.py",'r') as f:
        line = f.read()
    text=(line[line.index('config.') + 7:line.index(' import')])
    linenew = line.replace(text, fname)
    with open("pytestLoop/config/constants.py",'w') as f:
        f.write(linenew)
```

Opening a file in write mode automatically replaces the old content.